# Directory.CreateDirectory() created a folder with name that was supposed to be a file

Tags: unity, c#, xml, path, filestream

i am experiencing some problem here , i have a path :

"/folder/folderagain/file.xml"

i tried to use Directory.CreateDirectory() to create all folder (in case one of them is missing) and then reuse the path to create a file in another place inside the script. But instead a folder named "file.xml" was created by Directory.CreateDirectory() and my script got blocked from creating the file .

I managed to solve this problem by creating 2 different path , one of them end with file.xml and the other does not. But is there any better way to do it ? can i tell Directory.CreateDirectory() to create only folder ??

look at screenshot below , there's System.UnautorizedAccessException error because my script trying to create file named "keymap.xml" but a folder with the exact name already exist so it thrown that error .

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Path.GetDirectoryName()` to get everything except the last segment of the path, which is filename in your situation.

Comment: worked thank you ^^